# How to run maven project in Docker using Dockerfile when I have a custom repository

Tags: java, maven, docker, dependencies

I have a project called `escomled-machinelearning` that uses `Blackboard hazelcast instance` from other project called `escomled-common`. I have added the `escomled-common`  in `<dependencies>` of the `escomled-machinelearning` project. The project works, but when I try to run it in a Docker container using `Dockerfile`, it gives me an error:

> com.escomled.machinelearning:escomled-machine-learning:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at escomled:escomled-common:jar:0.0.1

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine as build-env
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN mvn package

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
WORKDIR /app
CMD java -jar app.jar
COPY --from=build-env /app/target/*.jar app.jar
```

I think the problem is that maven is trying to find `escomled:escomled-common:jar:0.0.1` in `maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine`. HELP

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `settings.xml` file that points to your custom respository. This is document in the dockerhub page for the [maven image](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/).

> To add your custom settings.xml file to the image use
>
> COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/

Comment: To do this when I have a <localRepository> or no?

Comment: I've been looking how to use `settings.xml` file and I can't succeed, can you help me ?